# Not able to perform String Splitting

Tags: java, split

I have a string in which i am not able to find a way out to split it where ever necessary.
Below is the scenario.

I am using java

```
String queryString = "String1=1&String2=2&String3=3&String31=31&String32=32....&String4=4";
```

I wanted the output something like below

```
String1=1
String2=2
String3=3&String31=31&String32=32....
String4=4
```

I tried `queryString.split("&");` but it splits String3,Strin31,String32...and so on as well.

Please help me out in this

Comment: What is the rule that makes `String2=2&String3=3` splittable, but not `String3=3&String31=31`?

Comment: @assylias I suspect it's because "3x" is considered part of "3".

Comment: Here String3 is the URL. So to be more precise i can replace String3 in the following way : URL=http:www.someurl.com/request1&request2=somedata&request3=someotherdata/

Comment: @KSMANOJ Why don't you rewrite your question with actual data? The answer to "how can I parse this URL" is not necessarily the same as what you have asked so far.

Comment: post an actual example. also, how do you get this string in the first place ? (and therefore, how do you know the specific url part starts, and how do you know it ends ?

Answer (score 1):

If you accept to do it in another way this is the snippet for it....

But i feel it is not at all recommendable...

I'm just want to remain you about [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)...  Is it not suitable for your requirement.

My code is here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String queryString = "String1=1&String2=2&String3=3&String31=31&String32=32&String4=4";
    int count = 1;
    String queryParam = "";
    try{
        while(count == 1 || queryParam.length() > 0){
            queryParam = queryString.substring(queryString.indexOf("String" + count + "="),queryString.indexOf("String" + ++count + "=")-1);
            System.out.println(queryParam);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        queryParam = queryString.substring(queryString.indexOf("String" + --count + "="));
        System.out.println(queryParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi naveen please vist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543676/how-to-parse-this-querystring-which-is-a-resultant-of-json-response

Comment: Then which i mentioned is exact... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a [lookahead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) to your regular expression for splitting.

If you only want to split into substrings starting with `String<digit>`, so `String1`, `String2`, `String3`, `String4`..., but not `String11`, `String31` etc (these have 2 digits), you can use a lookahead (along with the `"&"` delimiter) that checks the next substring is of that form:

```java
queryString.split("&(?=String[0-9]=)")
```

The `"String[0-9]="` regular expression only matches substrings of the form `String<digit>`, followed by a `=` sign (without the `=` it would also match the beginning of a `String<digit><digit>` substring, like `String31`). For a different criterion for splitting, you can replace this regular expression with whatever suits your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with some regex to split it the way you want, but I would recommend you change the & market to something else, or group the results that start with "String3" and join them afterwards.