# How to parse this queryString which is a resultant of JSON response

Tags: java, json, query-string

I have parsed a JSON response and got the String below :

```
String queryString = "AQB=1&v1=somev1data&v25=somev25data&URL=http://www.someurl.com/configure/getvalues/request1=req1Passed&data2=somedataPassed&ce=UTF-8&ARB=1";
```

When i split the above queryString the output should be :

```
AQB=1
v1=somev1data
v25=somev25data
URL=http://www.someurl.com/configure/getvalues/request1=req1Passed&data2=somedataPassed
ce=UTF-8
ARB=1
```

NOTE :
queryString always changes and the URL parameters also always changes.
AQB,v1.....v30,p1....p30,ce,pre,pe,URL,ARB are all the predefined variable names.

Comment: the URL param is not encoded, therefore there is no way to know where it ends, so it is likely any parsing algorithm will stop at the first `&` encountered.

Comment: You posted the same kind of question just before 20 min.Why you posted again

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542313/not-able-to-perform-string-splitting same type of  question

Comment: People were getting confused by String3, String31, String32 so the reason i posted in a new thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is NOT possible unless the URL parameter is properly URL-encoded, so the "&" characters will be escaped in order not to be interpreted as field separators.

The string should be encoded like this:

```
String queryString = "AQB=1&v1=somev1data&v25=somev25data&URL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.someurl.com%2Fconfigure%2Fgetvalues%2Frequest1%3Dreq1Passed%26data2%3DsomedataPassed&ce=UTF-8&ARB=1";
```

As it is formatted in your question, the string cannot be parsed successively.

Comment: i used queryString = URLDecoder.decode(JSONResponse, "UTF-8");  and as a result i get the above.

Comment: you were right. I got the solution now. I had to take JSON response as queryString and after splitting it with '&', for the resultant i need to use URLDecoder.decode();

Thank you all for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(queryString, "&");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
  System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

As another poster suggests, the only thing now left is to take care of the URL